# Не работает регулярное выражение, в онлайн тестере работает

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, laravel

Вот [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/L5JYtJ/1), тут она у меня работает, однако у меня на сервере нет.

Использую:

```
$reg = "/(\\tx0|^)key2(\\v)(.+?)(\\tx0)/";
$text = "key1\vvalue1\tx0key2\vvalue2\tx0key3\vvalue3\tx0";

$value = preg_match_all($reg, $text);
```

Comment: Вы пробовали вашу строку вывести на консоль? Вы тестировали регулярку на совсем другой строке. [**Вот так работает**](https://ideone.com/GVyMYE).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да.. кажется проблема в '\\' потому что с обычным слешем все работает... даже не знаю что ему не нравится

Comment: Как это "не знаю"? Когда вы пишите `"\n"`, вы разве ожидаете увидеть в строке слеш и `n`? Разве не знак перехода на новую строку?

Comment: В общем, используйте `$reg = "/(\tx0|^)key2(\v)(.+?)(\tx0)/";`, но я не понимаю, зачем тут столько групп.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброй ночи. А у Вас вывод ошибок включён? Уберите, для начала, "g".

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g' in /home/slonik/localhost/www/index.php on line 160
```

И я добавил бы третий параметр

```
preg_match_all($reg, $keys, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Результат такой

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  x0key2value2    x0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  x0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => value2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  x0
    )

)
```

Comment: Доброй! У меня все это дело в laravel и ошибок в консоль не выдает при выполнении.. Модификатор g у меня не стоит, это невнимательно скопировал с онлайн тестера, извиняюсь

Comment: А при чём тут консоль? Ответ обновил

Comment: И ещё. У Вас есть $text, а в функцию Вы подставляете $keys

Comment: тоже опечаточка, поправил. вывод $matches пустой массив размером 5..

Comment: С опечатками совсем плохо. Вводите в заблуждение)))